# Tasks show up even when i am not giving a upstream or downstream in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am not sure if this is suppose to be like this or not but lets say I am making a dag with 4 task and I put only 3 task in the steam so why is the 4th task also showing up and running??

EX:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('example_dag_one',
            schedule_interval='@daily',
            catchup=False,
            default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command='stuff',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test',
    bash_command='stuff',
    dag=dag)

    t3 = BashOperator(
        task_id='stop',
        bash_command='more stuff',
        dag=dag)
t4 = BashOperator(
        task_id='test2',
        bash_command='more stuff',
        dag=dag)

t1>>t2>>t3
```

so I expect only 3 tasks to show up  in my dag but for some reason all 4 show up.
why is t4 showing up?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators have a trigger_rule that defines how the task gets triggered. The default all_success rule dictates that the task should be triggered when all upstream dependent tasks have reached the success state.
If you don't specify the upstream, then the task will be triggered when you trigger the dag.

Once you created a task and mentioned the dag, it will be part of that dag. Setting up/down stream is only for establishing a relationship between tasks, which task will be triggered will be determined by upstream task and trigger rule.

Comment: so if i don't want a task to be executed is their no way to do it other then to comment it?

Comment: @Andy_101, creating an instance of an operator is results in the creation of a task object. Check this link: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/9e150cf17c4f279df7d9290aec3c7c726d61c32e/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L79 . If you want to skip task then you have to use SkipMixin. Check this link: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/models/skipmixin.py#L33